Locus of orthocenters gives extraneous solutions
I have recently tried to solve the following problem:
"Let A and B be the point of intersection between $\gamma:x^2+y^2-4x+4y=0$ and the x-axis and let $P(x_p;y_p)\in \gamma$. Determine the locus of othocenters of $\triangle APB$ as $P$ varies".

My attempt: After showing that $A(0;0)$ and $B(0;4)$, i calculated the lines which represent, respectively, the height in respect to $AB$ and to $PB$; their equations are:
$$\begin{cases}x=x_p\\
y=\dfrac{4-x_p}{y_p}x \end{cases}$$ A general orthocenter $H(x;y)$ is given by the intersection of those two lines (I think there is no need to calculate the third height). Knowing that $P$ satisfies the equation of $\gamma$, I expressed the coordinates of $P$ as a function of the $H$ ones and substituted in the equation of $\gamma$.
$$\begin{cases} x_p=x\\ y_p=\dfrac{4-x}{y}x \end{cases} \hspace{2cm}x^2_p+y^2_p-4x_p+4y_p=0$$
I got $\hspace{0,1cm}x^2+\dfrac{x^2}{y^2}(x^2-8x+16)-4x+4\dfrac{x}{y}(4-x)=0 \hspace{7cm}$ After expanding the brakets and factoring $\dfrac{x}{y^2}$:
$$\frac{x}{y^2}(xy^2+x^3-8x^2+16x-4y^2+16y-4xy)=0$$ Factoring this was really hard (do you have any suggestions/tips to make it easier?) but I eventually got: $$\frac{x}{y^2}(x-4)(x^2+y^2-4x-4y)=0$$ The solutions of this equations are $x=0 \vee x=4 \vee (x^2+y^2-4x-4y)=0 \hspace{1cm}$ with $y\neq 0$ This is the graph of this equation: 2 vertical lines and the circumference. Sadly it is a bit buggy but the spaces you see are actually 4 points: A, B, (0;4), (4;4).
The issue: my book, however, states that the locus of points is only the circumference, and without any restrictions... I graphed the points with geogebra and the locus does, indeed, appear to be only a circumference. I understand that you get the vertical lines when the triangle $\triangle APB$ degenerates, but I have no idea how to remove them, why the points (0;4) and (4;4) are excluded and what I have done wrong. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

You just have to treat yp=0 separetely. And for the lines x=0 gives xp=0 x=4 gives yp=4, yp=0

You can avoid all algebra just by noting that $\angle AHB=135°$ (because $\angle APB=45°$). Hence $H$ lies on the reflection of the circle about the $x$-axis.

@Intelligentipauca First, thanks for the answer. Why is $\angle AHB=135^{\circ}?$. And why does it imply that the locus is the symmetrical of the circumference about the $x$-axis?

See this figure. To see that $\angle APB=45°$ consider $P=(4, -4)$. Of course this works when $P$ lies on the lower arc. If $P$ lies on the upper arc, then $\angle APB=135°$ and $\angle AHB=45°$.

@Intelligentipauca I think I understand, thank you! Can I also ask you why you can conclude that the locus is the symmetrical about the x axis of the circle?

Point $H$ must lie on a circular arc subtended by chord $AB$. For any point $H'$ on the upper arc $AB$ you have $AH'B=180°-45°=135°$. But $H$ cannot be on the upper arc of the given circle, hence it must be on a congruent circle sharing the same chord $AB$.

@Intelligentipauca While trying to understand your solution I came up with a similar geometric one. I cannot understand how angles relate to the last part

I'm afraid I don't understand how you apply Euclid's first theorem (?) to the triangles $△$ and $△′$.

@Intelligentipauca you are right, I just realized it can't be applied to prove the congruence, sorry. I was able to prove that $\angle AHB = \angle AH'B = 135^{\circ}$ but nothing more

You get extra solutions because your first system gives for the ordinate of $H$: $$y={4x_P-x_P^2\over y_P},$$ which is singular for $y_P=0$. You can circumvent the issue by noting that $4x_P-x_P^2=y_P^2+4y_P$. Plugging that into the equation for $y$ you can simplify $y_P$ and get: $$y=y_P+4,$$ which is not singular at $y_P=0$.

@Intelligentipauca what a beautiful solition! So I get extraneous solitions because in the 2 systems it was implicit that $y_p≠0$ and $y≠0$
? You should also have the condition $y_p≠0$ but, if I am correct, the advantage is that's something not intrinsic in the equation so you can ignore this condition. Am i right? By the way, thank you so much for your constant effort on this question

Here's a geometric and "simple" solution.
Let's construct first of all the centroid of triangle $ABP$. If $M$ is the midpoint of $AB$, the centroid $G$ is that point on segment $PM$ satisfying $MG={1\over2}GP$.
According to Euler’s Line theorem, the orthocenter $H$ of $PAB$ lies on ray $OG$ and $GH=2OG$. Hence triangles $OGM$ and $PGH$ are similar, with similarity ratio $2$ and $PH$ is parallel to $OM$ and of double length: $PH=2OM$. It follows that $H$ is the image of $P$ under a translation of vector $(0,2OM)$ and the locus of $H$ is then the translated of circle $ABP$. This is another circle, whose center $O''$ is then the reflection of $O$ about point $M$.


Thank you so much for this beautiful solution.  You can conclude that $\triangle PGH$ is similar to $\triangle OGM$ because they have 2 sides with the same ratio?

Two sides with the same ratio and the angles between them congruent (vertical angles). It's SAS criterion.

Another solution:

Its clear that $p=h$, and $PB \perp PD$
So product of their slopes is $-1$.
$$\left(\frac{q}{p-4}\right)\left(\frac kh\right)=-1$$$$q=-\frac{h(p-4)}{k}$$$$q=-\frac{h(h-4)}{k}$$
and $$p=h$$
$(p,q)$ satisfies the equation of the circle, so just substitute the values of $p$ and $q$ with their values obtained in terms of $h$ and $k$, and replace $h$ with $x$ and $k$ with $y$ to get the locus.

First of all, thank you for this solution . The problem is that it is basically the same approach I have used in my solution and  as you can see, it leads to some extraneous solutions. Maybe you can spot what's wrong
